# setTimeout and redirect with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I am using jQuery to Countdown timer and then redirect to a particular page.
If the user touches the link (Circle in my case), it'll redirect to another page.

This is my code. How do I redirect my page after 5 seconds?

```
//Some API call
success: function(response){
    console.log("Server response: ", response.redirect);
    $('#cmx_portal_oauth_welcome_dialog').popup("open"); // Opening something!
    $('.redirect').attr('href',response.redirect); //Response.redirect contains my forwarding URL.
}
setTimeout( window.location.replace(response.redirect ), 5000);
```

Does the setTimeout work well with window.location.replace(response.redirect)?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't... there isn't another way to set a timeout, anyway.

Comment: So, is your code not working?

Comment: I'd assume he asks this because chrome blocks all redirects called by non-click/button events. I'm not sure if it's called directly( setTimeout) would work

Comment: @ochi yes my code does not work. that's what confused me. it's surprising someone gave me a -1 for asking a simple question.. Oh well .. this is how I get greeted for being a newbie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) takes a function as a first parameter that is executed after n seconds. This will work:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.replace(response.redirect);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: That's correct, without the `function(){ ... }` it will be executed immediately. [Here is an example of that](http://jsfiddle.net/0boLeezj/).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Your example's a tad hard to see, here's a modified one: http://jsfiddle.net/0boLeezj/2/

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right. `setTimeout` takes a string that will be eval'd or a function. To not use the function, you would need to wrap your code around quotes.

```
setTimeout('window.location.replace(response.redirect)', 5000);
```

Comment: MDN recommends against using a string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout